# Syntax error moving a string defined with EQU to a register

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2017, masm, masm32

I am trying store a few prompts as EQU constants to print out to the screen. When i attempt to build i get a syntax error when i attempt to move it into edx register. Can you guys help me understand what is going on please? I cant find any information on this what so ever. The error i get is:

> LPT_alp2.asm(48): error A2008: syntax error : "

```
    include irvine32.inc

.data
;

a1  BYTE 11h, 22h, 33h, 44h, 55h, 66h
a2  WORD 1234h, 2345h, 3456h, 4567h
a3  DWORD 12345h, 23456h, 34567h, 45678h

s1 EQU <"My name is ",10,13,0>
s2 EQU <"Assembly Language Project 2",10,13,0>
s3 EQU <"You have selected option ",10,13,0>
s4 EQU <"Sorry but we are all out of that Main Meal selection.",10,13,0>
s5 EQU <"Select a Main Meal Option",10,13,0>
s6 db "1. Turkey Sandwich",10,13,0
s7 db "2. Hot Ham and Cheese Sandwich",10,13,0
s8 db "3. Garden Salad",10,13,0
s9 db "4. Exit",10,13,0
s10 EQU <"Choice ",0>
s11 EQU <"I’m sorry, I guess we don’t have anything today.",10,13,0>
s12 EQU <"We hope that you will come back again.",10,13,0>

sHelp BYTE 5 DUP("**HELP**")

;

count BYTE 0
sum1 BYTE ?
sum2 BYTE ?

.code
main proc
    ; 

    mov edx, s1
    call WriteString
    call crlf

mov edx, s2
call WriteString
call crlf


;menu:





;LOOP menu

mov eax,0
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,0
mov edx,0


mov al,[a1+3]
mov bx,[a2+6]
mov ecx,[a3+12]
movzx edx,[a2+2]

call DumpRegs


Call CrLf
invoke ExitProcess, 0

main endp
end main
```

Comment: You can't move an entire string to a register. You probably want to get an address to a string, but that requires it being declared somewhere in a data section to begin with. `mov edx, s1` was the same as saying `mov edx, <"You have selected option ",10,13,0>` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: i thought that s1(The string) would be an address im trying to move into edx ?

Comment: No with EQU it is literall searching and replacing `s1` with what is on the right hand side of the EQU. I think you want something like `s1 db "My name is ",10,13,0` . That creates that string in the `data` section and you can get the address of that with `mov edx, offset s1`

Comment: ok  that makes sense i didnt know i would have to use a db i thought that was the purpose of using EQU instead.

Comment: since I just need to print that string to the screen

Comment: EQU doesn't allocate data, `db` does. EQU is effectively like C macros. It does text replacement. It equates an identifiers with a number or text. To print data to the string you have to allocate it in a data section (ie. with `db` and then use the `offset` keyword like my earlier comment to retrieve the address of it.

Comment: Is it possible to print a string without allocating data

Comment: In the sense you are asking - No. The string has to be somewhere in memory. In a data section, on the stack etc, but it needs to be somewhere physically in memory to print. EQU just doesn't allocate memory. You had lines in your code done properly like `s6`, `s7`, `s8`, `s9` which all used `db` to allocate space in the data section with the strings.

Comment: The way i understood it is that EQU creates a constant in a sense instead of a variable. I intended for all of the strings that are not menu items to be constants. I know there should be a way i can do this i just cant find any information on it. I know the way that you recommended will work the way my code is written, and you explained why it doesnt work when i try to move it into a register which helps alot . Im really trying to learn what changes i need to make to make it work how i intend.

Comment: assembler doesn't have `const` feature of C/C++ like languages. You can on x86 win32 OS have particular page of memory set to be non-writeable (I guess the MASM may have some directives to set up certain data segment as read-only - but I'm not MASM user), which will make anything defined there by `db` as "constants". `EQU` is not constant in variable-like definition, it's constant macro to be replaced with the value before the assembling of source text starts.

Comment: Actually with windows executables the code segment by default is read-only (unless you will call the WinAPI to make those memory pages write-able). So whichever string definition you will move into code, it will be protected against modification. Just make sure you don't execute it. I.e. the `someString db "lorem ipsum", 13, 10` can be safely placed after `main endp` in your example code. If you would place it for example ahead of `Call CrLf`, the string data would be executed as machine instructions, causing havoc... (you may for fun check in debugger in disassembly, what would be executed)

Comment: http://oopweb.com/Assembly/Documents/ArtOfAssembly/Volume/Chapter_8/CH08-3.html#HEADING3-34   - wow, actually it's just compile time check, not enforced during runtime (while the code segment is read-only at runtime, that's enforced by windows OS, until the code itself will ask it to change the permissions).